Double Pane vinyl windows retain water in window sash after rain stops and needs to be vacuumed or sucked out
During and after heavy rains some of the double pane windows leak over the sash and into the house. After the rains stop there is still water remaining in the sash and needs to be vacuumed out or removed by towels or other method. The weep holes appear to be open but when I move the flap nothing comes out.

Flap? I've not seen that. Weep holes are open to the outside and should freely drain.

this needs a picture

@UnhandledExcepSean yes, flaps, like these: https://www.windowpartscenter.com/cdn/shop/products/ss20003-weep-hole-cover-double-hung-176.jpg

OP, can you confirm continuity of drainage between exterior of frame, through weep hole flap, to window sash channel?
